# What's the design pattern for WordPress like module/plugin management?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a script. The idea is to provide customers with a basic script for free and if anyone needs s/he can integrate new add on(s). So it's quite similar to WordPress module + plugin integration. I am curious to know the design pattern WordPress uses for this purpose. Right now I'm thinking about using Observer or Decorator pattern.

Comment: I doubt that Wordpress uses design patterns at all.

Comment: "Wordpress" and "design patterns" in the same sentence? You really made my day.

Answer (score 0):

When you active a plugin in your admin panel, you are appending the root file of the plugin to the execution WordPress queue.
For example, you can create a class or functions in your plugin file, and then call in the root plugin file those methods, or hack some worpdress functions using add_filter add_action wp methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WordPress does use design patterns for writing plugins and themes.
All the modules from the plugin/theme work according to the WordPress design pattern. As, JokiRuiz gave example about the plugin activated, its also work according to the design pattern.

WordPress uses multiple types of design patterns:

1. Singleton pattern
2. Object oriented pattern
3. Procedure oriented pattern

It is, basically, if you want to expand the functionality of WordPress by plugins or themes, you have to use the WordPress calls [actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), where you can hook your code.

If you want to build any plugin you can start learning WordPress from [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/). WordPress has very well designed and maintained their documentation.